# Animation breaks binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-animation

I have a `ComboBox` whose `Opacity` property has the following binding:

```
Opacity="{Binding ElementName=stackPanel, Path=IsMouseOver, Converter={StaticResource mouseOverConverter}}"
```

Basically, if the `IsMouseOver` property is true, the `ComboBox` has an `Opacity` of 1, otherwise 0.4.

Now I apply this animation to the `ComboBox`:

```
private void AnimateComboBox()
{
  DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
  da.From = 0.4;
  da.To = 1;
  da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.8);
  da.AutoReverse = true;

  ComboClassList.BeginAnimation(ComboBox.OpacityProperty, da);  
}
```

That works well, but afterwards the binding of the `ComboBox` doesn't work anymore. The `Opacity` doesn't change when I move my mouse over the `StackPanel`. Why does the animation break my binding? Snoop says, the binding still exists, altough it's highlighted red in Snoop.

Comment: I deleted my answer because i miss the problem. One way binding broken doesn't seems the case.

Comment: please clarify your question, why do you want to add animation in code while it already works via setting up in XAML? Of course once you setup animation in code all values set via XAML will be overwritten. See this [WPF Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwi5_sXbgZzIAhUkGKYKHToNAsM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fvstudio%2Fms743230(v%3Dvs.100).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGMSO4IIv2O0gOK0YvJ8mQRqAFZBQ&sig2=NoPktI1J7mw2XmnM_ED5Ag&bvm=bv.103388427,bs.1,d.dGY)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The animation is by default holding the final property value. To change that, set its `FillBehavior` property to `Stop`:

```
var animation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = 0.4,
    To = 1,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.8),
    AutoReverse = true,
    FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
};
```

When the animation ends, the property will be set back to the value provided by the binding.

Comment: Yes, excactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much :)